# Control the order of nested if-else via promise or async await

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, angular-promise

I have  been struggling with a nested if-else which I would like to run all the conditions without returning, here's my code :

```
openMainModal: boolean;
openSecondaryModal: boolean;

mainFunction(isOpen : boolean) {
    isOpen ? this.openSecondaryModal = true : this.openMainModal = true;
    this.OpenModal():
}
OpenModal() {
    call to angular service...
    if (condition one = true) {
        do some logics....
    } else {
        if (!this.openSecondaryModal) {
            do some logics....
        }
    }
    if (condition two) {
        do some logics....
    } else {
        if (!this.openMainModal) {
            do some logics....
        }
    }
    this.openMainModal = false;
    this.openSecondaryModal = false:
}
```

the issue is both openMainModal and openSecondaryModal are having the value of true but somehow in the else when I console log it gets false despite that it's true, what you recommend to use in order to control the order of running code? can async-await or promise be used in this scenario?
also as general guidance, how do you suggest to simplify this code, since I want the entire function of openModal to run with all its conditions without returning in any of the condition being met?

Comment: yes, corrected the typo :) thanks

Comment: the last two lines at the end will always run, that's why `openMainModal` will always be `false`

Comment: @programmer - those lines occur after the conditional tests have occurred. Those lines are resetting them to their initial state. If you look in the `mainFunction()` you'll see the order of operation.

Comment: but the why inside the else before the if condition console log is false? and at the beginning of the function the console log prints true! why it turns from true to false I don't do any value flipping or reassigning from the beginning of the function until else which makes me doubt the order of code execution.

Comment: You haven't initialized them at declaration time either? if you want to ensure an initial state, why not initialize them as `false`? It likely won't make any difference, but just curious. There is something else going on here that you have not disclosed. What other code effects those two variables?

Comment: For example, does your code still work if you initialize both variables inside `mainFunction()` and them pass them as parameters to `OpenModal()`?

Comment: didn't try initialze them to false, but what baffles me i tried this and it doesn't work
mainFunction(isOpen : boolean) {
    isOpen ? this.openSecondaryModal = true : this.openMainModal = true;
    this.OpenModal():
this.openSecondaryModal = false; 
this.openMainModal = false;
}

Comment: @Randy Casburn tried passing them as parameters and it works! But still want to understand what's going on with my original code, if you have an explanation :)

Comment: me too (really - not really) - but you didn't provide any detail on the architecture of your code. Most likely culprit is the use of the 'this' keyword when not in the correct context or something.

Comment: Thank you :) Will take a closer look, do you recommend any improvements in the if else if else given that I want the entire function to be executed?